# The function $G(x) =(4\pi t)^{-d/2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} e^{\frac{-|x-y|^2}{4t}}|y|^k dy$ can be controlled when $|x|\rightarrow \infty$

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, integration

In this [paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272398/1-s2.0-S0022039600X00782/1-s2.0-S0022039696931964/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEDcaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQDupPydP66TFKIaldCmMZvWQU%2BxQQbKTb0mvVYeQp%2FyAwIhAJ1fQXgupzUfU5Pwk5i9gylGjDqIeq5SQu2Txp%2BGzJ57KrwFCLD%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEQBRoMMDU5MDAzNTQ2ODY1IgyuSbB%2B6y9fhO%2BVOekqkAVj7Uj51XmdcLkYxyn18OWriVS5H2VXuQIr9n81YIf%2FMn3A1grh%2FKdE2QDo7WAQswGqDq4Fe2kQhq1wIrhPSukarrA7uGd9BYRMRntj3JWsRwoWw2joPewe%2BuBZFZTv4Oh2PhccrhKrtgDuEbDPM8fIHrV0UKWQ48NILAhHKM7%2F7y6R2maMG%2B%2BkXn0iT4TIYy9V2kT%2FI2xHX%2BSTgCl3lOpTAqxO2CYdfhqn%2FPGgJh4dys9ZK56IxzI4CnKDG7rzbvjxQUXrq4VQj%2BhWqe5WcdzUg2t5lOgr7xZpVA%2BR7Iec9%2FmRUILEKX%2BAgzLitjyXYKKPBiEvp9gEfMTwCRt0J97ADAZC1NyDGi2Jz7SKqgKRSdnD637C%2F9p7xTf7iAAc6WOSVsTRUEuah%2BxbKq8DSrUjbkrSykQJYmjH9zQV0qcjSpY4Vn%2BfKELGQORlMT1%2BPuk2%2FemQzFSN%2BrEaBTIvfaunMTQ%2BIPkFjtInPkPOzjKEDMaXEMIvvfESXJ%2FPBq4jRY%2F%2BbipBeROU2DNPyZuJRJkA5gKr3O5g315aYHCfOrX%2BBCHZAQrEkPalpTvHifY4D7GpCmw5T0D%2FaYcMNyRBwGbO80FEbvEI%2BQNi5b21QDd42QgE9Qa%2BtC1MT9IIALchUXP4nftQSIfdKhegfbbQjudaxZzOR8kxiJ%2FR%2Bq%2B2dUnuetICD%2F58N7zdnuHPxWHcVTJu21yugPMqV0SunyMiopQY5OPgTVr95fdRocuMLdedQu9nrlsg0x2H3vh1MOjLLlQkmKPuKpRhjPcozmxSXFnKb1IjUbh%2Bo60q973QxovnPW8%2FwVdNxa192rXEHrUosyLayoMxBhnCCnx9Wxp7VEPCbpyjYc00BWqUhVd1iO3hVzD6lLKlBjqwAfBvqrE7VqGONtL8irrFHCR5rLcMwCb%2BviVN5lp4ioyuyjSZxf%2FM5v%2Fwi5wDBd5KDklajbvYq3TBOvW5%2BThRnXE%2FWG0zryiRybUWcxtghTbRbGZztc%2BtrJVX3Lm3%2FfoOwvvd4Tg1m8D2OBSUo4uA2Eft5kUpUtJnVwYwFpLUAgUmRXglqn4GVtnE2rDu8UW9DBh0lqM93UNIi0234jsrZTsRys9sdrfXP6Xs6shwIm4y&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230710T235216Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYVJ7ZWBG4%2F20230710%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=7690893b774d6cf762a351a7bc004377d18343a0b1e9f41867f1ab970884bf25&hash=fc536f2508881dc4428adc23ae8fd84c793d245e8ffd80d9cde70a0d8ec1bca7&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0022039696931964&tid=spdf-4228bc05-51e1-405f-940e-c0b61baaf69d&sid=71fadf265f80e94e2a6b7324384a1f4e2699gxrqa&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=041459035a0006575102&rr=7e4cb82a8bd300e8&cc=br), Lemma 6, Pinsky proves that $$H(x) =(4\pi t)^{-d/2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} e^{\frac{-|x-y|^2}{4t}}(1+|y|)^m \, dy$$ attains its maximum in $x=0$ for $m<0$. This can also be proven using the [Riesz rearrangement inequality][2].  My question at first was whether $$G(x) =(4\pi t)^{-d/2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} e^{\frac{-|x-y|^2}{4t}}|y|^k \, dy,$$ $k>0$, there is $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^d$ at which the integral reaches its maximum. This time it is not possible to use Riesz rearrangement inequality, as $|y|^k$, $k>0$ is non-decreasing.

In a comment of Christian Remling below, it was noted that $$(4\pi t)^{-d/2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} e^{\frac{-|x-y|^2}{4t}}|y|^k \, dy \rightarrow \infty \text{ as } |x|\rightarrow \infty.$$ So a question arose, whether there is any upper bound for $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} e^{\frac{-|x-y|^2}{4t}}|y|^k \, dy,$$ $k>0$, of polynomial type, so that I can control the growth of $G(x)$, possibly multiplying by $|x|^\beta$, for some $\beta <0$. Is there any result in this direction, or any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing some subtlety, but it looks obvious to me that the maximum is assumed at $x=0$ in the first case (we are dealing with averages of $(1+|y|)^m$ centered at $x$, and this function is largest near $y=0$). For the same reason, the second function grows without bound as $|x|\to\infty$.

Comment: PS: The claims near the end of your post are incorrect: $\int_0^{\infty} x^{3/2} e^{-(x-a)^2}\, dx \ge \int_a^{a+1}\ldots \ge a^{3/2}e^{-1}$

Comment: The function tends to infinity when $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling true, I will change the question, perhaps it is possible, according to your comment, to find a upper bound, in order to verify that $\lim_{a \rightarrow \infty} a^{\beta}\int_0^{\infty}x^{c}e^{-(x-a)^2}dx < \infty$, $\beta<0$, it will be possible?

Comment: Where you wrote $-n/2,$ did you mean $-d/2 \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy exactly, the correct one is $-d/2$.

Comment: It grows like $|x|^k$; it is better seen changing variables to put the $x$ inside the power.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Do you mean to say that there is a universal constant $ C>0$ such that $\int_{R^d} e^{-|x-y|^2}|y|^kdy \leq C|x|^k$? If so, perhaps I should choose $\beta = -k$ to have control from $0$ to $\infty$ of the integral.

Comment: Yes, exactly  but for large $|x|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, if $k\ge1$, then
$$G(x)=E|x+\sqrt{2t}Z|^k\le(|x|+\sqrt{2t}\|Z\|_k)^k,$$
by Minkowski's inequality, where $Z$ is a standard normal random vector in $\mathbb R^d$ and $\|Z\|_k:=(E|Z|^k)^{1/k}$. If $k\in(0,1)$, then
$$G(x)=E|x+\sqrt{2t}Z|^k\le|x|^k+(2t)^{k/2}\|Z\|_k^k.$$

Also, by Jensen's inequality,
$$G(x)\ge |x|^k$$
if $k\ge1$, and $G(x)\ge |x|^k-(2t)^{k/2}\|Z\|_k^k$ if $k\in(0,1)$.

So,
$$G(x)\sim|x|^k$$
as $|x|\to\infty$.

Comment: @losif Pinelis where can I find this notation you used in the demonstration above, it seems probabilistic. Any reference books?

Comment: @Ilovemath : $E$ denotes the expectation. It can be found in any probability textbook. So, $EX:=\int X\,dP$, where $X$ is a random variable and $P$ is the underlying probability measure. For "standard normal random vector", see e.g.[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Standard_normal_random_vector) and further references there.

Comment: Why the downvote? Anything wrong with this answer?